# C# Settings File doesn't show changes

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I was playing around with some settings in my C# console Application. I want to save a string to the settings.settings File, which worked by creating a setting in Designview (I called it teststring).
I assigned the Value "Hello World!". When I access it during runtime with `Properties.Settings.Default.teststring` I get back the assigned value. So far so good. Now this is where things get odd: When I assign a new value like `Properties.Settings.Default.teststring = "This is a new test"` and save it by `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`, the value gets saved as expected.

However: The Value in the Designview stays the same ("Hello World!") and when I now change the value in Design View, it does not affect the stored setting. It will return "This is a new test". The Scope of the Value is set to "User" of course, so that it can be changed during runtime.

What do I have to change so that the settings-Design-View stays updated. And where, if not in the settings.settings file, is the Value "This is a new test" stored?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I'm posting this as an answer, but the updated settings are stored in a text file `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<company_name>\<app_name>randomcharacters\1.0.0.0\user.config`

You can programmatically get the path with

```
public static string GetDefaultExeConfigPath(ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel)
{
    try
    {
        var UserConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(userLevel);
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(UserConfig.FilePath);
    }
    catch (ConfigurationException e)
    {
        return e.Filename;
    }
}
```

Not sure how to answer the designer thing or if this is what you're after, but maybe it helped you.

Comment: So I'm really confused now. There is user.config, app.config, settings.settings and [AppName].exe.Config. Does anybody know the difference and which command writes to what? `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` writes to user.config. `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);` writes to [AppName].exe.Config. The Designview to Settings.settings. Does anybody know which command writes to Settings.Settings and what the app.config is all about?

Comment: user.config is the saved user settings. settings.settings is Visual Studio specific to edit the values and compile them, which will produce appname.exe.config, which are the default stored values